# ProcessBuilder for .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

In Java I have code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(fileName, license, session, server, db, user, pass, port);
Process process = builder.start();
```

And in .NET Core I tried this:

```
String builder = license + " " + session + " " + server + " " + db + " " + user + " " + pass + " " + port;

Precess process = new Process();
process.Start(fileName, builder);
```

And the version with ProcessStartInfo:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.Arguments = builder;
```

but it does not work. I have error:

```
Member 'Process.Start(string, string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
```

How in .NET Core should I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
var process = Process.Start(fileName, builder);
```

As the error message tells you, `Start` is a `static` method and you cannot call static methods on class instances (you can in Java, but that's still a warning).

Also note that you may have to manually quote arguments containing spaces, which Java would have done for you, cf. the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netframework-4.7#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_Arguments).

Comment: thank you. I do not know how but when I looked at MSDN I thought that was not Process.Start(); but object.Start() in example... That's why I write my question, I was confused.